# Trying to write a regex for a alphanumeric string like - R51/53

Tags: java, regex

Hi
I want a regular expression (Java) for a string in the following form:
Starts with R or S , then space , then number or number / number or number/number/number
examples:
R 51/53 , R 41, R 43, S 36/37/39, S 2, S 24, S 26/2

thanks in advance

Comment: @Tim: a good question, I am afraid you'll have a ready-to-use answer from some Regex Magician in less than 3 minutes though.

Comment: @Grz, that is unfortunate. I believe SO would would impart more knowledge if people were helped to an answer in this kind of questions. (Though I'm guilty as well.)

Comment: I tried Joost Diepenmaat , it is working ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the basic regex is:

```
[RS] ([0-9]+)(/[0-9]+){0,2}
```

but it needs some masking, I guess:

```
String regex = "[RS] ([0-9]+)(/[0-9]+){0,2}";
System.out.println (param + "\t" + param.matches (regex));
```

I'm always confused, because sed, java, scala - all have different opinions what to mask and what not. :)

(update: testet, modified masking)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`^[RS]\s\d+(?:/\d+){0,2}$`

Explanation:

`^` start of line

`[RS]` Character class matching 1 occurence of R or S

`\s` whitespace, this will also match a tab or other whitespace, can be replaced with a space.

`\d+` 1 or more numbers

`(?:/\d+){0,2}` Non-capturing group (better performance) of a / followed by 1 or more numbers, occuring between 0 and 2 times.

`$` end of line

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like

```
[RS] [0-9]+(/[0-9]+)*
```

Comment: Didn't OP mean 'number/number/number' as the longest possible suffix?

Comment: [RS] [0-9]+(/[0-9]+)(/[0-9]+)?(/[0-9]+)? if number/number/number is the longest allowed.

Comment: or {0,2} as repeating specifier for the (/NUM).

Answer (score 1):

```
[RS] (\d+|\d+/\d+|\d+/\d+/\d+)
```

Comment: how can we check if a long text has that regex please ?

Comment: @Mohammed: using another regex? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: No , it is workig , but if i have text , for example : " thank you Joost for helping me in finding R 52/25  regex  " how can i make sure that long sentence has that regex ?

Comment: @Mohammed: regular expressions that aren't fixed to the start or end of a string (and mine isn't) don't care about the length of the text. Unless your text is extremely long (like more than a Gb or so), you don't need to worry about it. If your text is really unwieldy, you might not want to use a RegEx for a simple match like this.

Answer (score 0):

Hum I think of :

```
'(R|S) ((\d+)/){0,2}\d+'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% confident but I think this: `R|S' '[0-9](/[0-9])*`

Comment: allows more than 3 times /NUM.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one: (R|S) (\d/?)+

Comment: This would allow a trailing slash